# Make column width in shiny automatically fit to values

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Shiny in R. I have a table in the shiny app in which I am trying to change the column widths based on the values in each column.

Currently it seems as though the column width is based on the header value and text below is wrapping. How can I override this?

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library (formattable)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("DT table in Shiny"),
                mainPanel(
                  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")))

server <- function(input, output){
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable( {
    df6
    return(as.datatable(formattable(df6, lapply(4:5, function(col){area(col = col) ~ color_tile("red", "green")}))))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: can you post an reproducible example ?